# Custom Control with Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf

I have created a custom control for which I would like to be able to add resources. Right now I am enclosing the custom control in a ContentControl as below. Would it be possible to change MyControl such that I can have a ResourceDictionary inside of MyControl? Maybe like an attached DependencyProperty?

```
<ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            ...
        </ContentControl.Resources>

        <utils:MyControl
            Propery_A="{Binding Some_A}"
            Propery_B="{Binding Some_B}"
            DeleteButtonContent="{StaticResource customDeleteButtonContent}"
            />
    </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to change MyControl such that I can have a ResourceDictionary inside of MyControl?

I may have misunderstood your issue but you could just inherit from `FrameworkElement` or any of its descendants, like for example `Control`:

```
public class MyControl : Control
...
```

Then you can set its `Resources` property like you set it for any other control:

```
<utils:MyControl
            Propery_A="{Binding Some_A}"
            Propery_B="{Binding Some_B}"
            DeleteButtonContent="{StaticResource customDeleteButtonContent}"
    <utils.MyControl.Resources>
        ...
    </utils.MyControl.Resources>
</utils:MyControl>
```

No need to wrap your control in a `ContentControl`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is a simple as you say. Sometimes ones doesn't see the forest for the trees.